# Limit of a strange sum

Tags: limits, functions, summation

For a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and each integer $n\geq 1$, the function $B_n(f): [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $B_n(f)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})\binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$.
For any integer $m\geq 0$ let $f_m(x) = x^m$. Show that for each integer $m\geq 0$ and each $x\in [0,1], B_n(f_m)(x) \to f_m(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Earlier in the question I showed that $\binom{n}{k}(\frac{k}{n})^m = \binom{n-1}{k-1}\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}a_{n, m, l}(\frac{k-1}{n-1})^{m-1-l}$ where $a_{n, m, l} = \binom{m-1}{l}(\frac{1}{n-1})^l (\frac{n-1}{n})^{m-1}$, and so I wanted to compute the limit of just this part and then use this to show the result I want, but can't compute the limit. I also tried to induct but that hasn't seemed to work.

Can someone give some guidance?

Comment: Strange? Not really: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions

Comment: It'd be nice if you could give some insight into how the earlier result can be used to deduce the required result. Focusing on that would probably be more useful than focusing on the wording of the title.

Comment: You can apply the identity shown in the previous part of the question to obtain a recursive relation of $B_n(f_m)$ in terms of $B_n(f_{m-1})$, then the limit follows from induction on $m$. (This is a past paper question from 2017.)